# Service Application Fail-over

Tags: architecture, infrastructure

I am not seeing in the technical docs about how to deploy redundant service applications for a farm.  I am seeking confirmation about my idea of having two web servers responsible for cross-farm application services with a load balancer in front.  The other farms would access those services through the load balancer.

Can anyone tell me about the feasibility of this idea or documentation the describes SP 2010 Service Application Fail-over strategies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service Applications are redundant if you make sure that you install and start the services on multiple load balanced application servers. SharePoint 2010 handles the load balancing for you.

Regarding the fail-over strategies you have to look into the different services and if they use a database for storage or not. The databases that the SA uses must be made redundant using normal strategies (clustering, mirroring or by configuring a fail-over server for the SA). You might get some data loss with SAs that do not use SQL for storage such as Excel services and Access services.

When it comes to the actual service applications they normally work using timer jobs, these timer jobs are executed on the first available server and if it fails it will run on the next server serving that SA during next execution.